# The UITextView inside the UITableView is hidden behind the keyboard

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have placed the UITextView inside one UITableViewCell of the UITableView, but when the Keyboard is displayed, the UITextView is hidden. I also have a UITextField, which is displayed properly above the keyboard.

Here is the code that follows the keyboard display.

```swift
    func setupKeyboardNotification() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow),
                                               name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
                                               object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide),
                                               name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
                                               object: nil)
    }

    @objc private func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification?) {
        guard
            let userInfo = notification?.userInfo,
            let rect = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect,
            let duration = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double else {
            return
        }
        let bottomMargin = 50.0

        self.bottomConstraint.constant = -rect.size.height + bottomMargin
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }

    @objc private func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification?) {
        guard
            let userInfo = notification?.userInfo,
            let duration = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double else {
            return
        }
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
```

How can I modify the UITextView so that it appears above the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

For keyboard, there are many ways to resolve it. Personally, I recommend using IQKeyboardManager library to implement in your UIKit view controllers if possible. It is a popular and well-maintained library - https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager.